# Example of an integrable function with an entire extension and whose derivative only vanishes at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I am looking for a function $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ with the following properties:

1. $f$ is entire.
2. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t)| \ dt < \infty$ i.e. the restriction of $f$ to the real line is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.
3. $\lim_{|t| \to \infty} f'(t) = 0$ i.e. the restriction of $f'$ to the real line is in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$.
4. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f'(t)| \ dt = \infty$  i.e. the restriction of $f'$ the real line is *not* in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

So far I've at least had some success coming up with an example of an entire function $g$ whose restriction to the real line is $C_0(\mathbb{R})$, but not $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. For instance, $g(z) = \frac{e^{-z^2} - 1}{z}$ seems to do the trick. I'm not sure if there's an antiderivative $f$ of this $g$ with the desired property though.

Comment: Typo at 4. you mean $f'$, not $f$.

Comment: @AD: fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
f(z)=\int_0^z\frac{\sin(w^2)}{w}\,dw-\frac{\pi}{4}.
$$
$f$ is an even entire function. As the real variable $t \to \infty$, $f(t)$ behaves like $O(t^{-2})$, so, in particular,  that $\lim_{t\to\pm\infty}f(t)=0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f(t)|\,dt<\infty$. On the other hand
$$
f'(z)=\frac{\sin(z^2)}{z}
$$
and
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f'(t)|\,dt=2\int_0^\infty\frac{|\sin(t^2)|}{t}\,dt=\int_0^\infty\frac{|\sin(u)|}{u}\,du=\infty.
$$

Comment: Thanks. I've made a few changes, hope you don't mind. (1) I corrected $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ which I think you meant. (2) In the countour integral defining $f$ I changed $x$ to $w$ since $x$ feels like a real variable to me. (3) You can't mean that $f(z) = O(z^{-2})$ as the complex variable $z \to \infty$ since that makes $f$ constant by Liouville. Anyway this holds along the real line, so this is OK.

Comment: No problema, thanks for the corrections.